# How to Customise Header for guest and logged in user in magento2 programmatically?

Tags: luma-theme, magento2.3.2

[image]I want different top header section for guest and login user.

> **Guest user header option**
>
> "Hi Guest" + sign-in option
>
> **Login user header option**
>
> "Hi [User Name]"

How do I perform it programmatically?

Comment: Are you using default magento 2 luma theme? And what is version of your magento?

Comment: yes and using magento 2.3.2 with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this requirement using a Plugin.

**File - Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" type="\Vendor\Module\Block\Html\MyCustomHeader" />
</config>
```

***File - \Vendor\Module\Block\Html\MyCustomHeader.php***

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Html;


class MyCustomHeader extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header
{
    protected $_template = 'Magento_Theme::html/header.phtml';
    protected $_customerSession ;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, array $data = []) 
    {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession ;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Custom Logic For Welcome Text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getWelcome()
    {
        if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return parent::getWelcome();
        }
        else {
            return __('Hi Guest!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked.

Comment: Sir I have added an image. I want to know how to change the "Myaccount" to logged in user name?

Answer (score 0):

> Actual file path vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
>
> Override header.phtml file app/design/frontend/vendore/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

After that change

```
$welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome();
```

to

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   $welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome();
} 
else{
    $welcomeMessage = 'Hi Guest!';
}
```

**sign-in option automatically remove for login customer.**

Comment: is this feasible while designing any other website using magento

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Suppose I am designing a website using magento 2 then will this change in code work for the same task

Comment: If you will create another website with Magento then also this code is usable for you.

Comment: Ok thank you. and if I use the other theme and not luna?

Comment: 90% the most of the theme using same file. Let me know if you have issue in another theme.

Comment: app/design/frontend/ frontend folder contains magento folder rest is empty

Comment: You will first create custom theme after that override file. https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html

Comment: If I want to call this from app/ code without using design how this should be done

Comment: I am new to this. please give me a detailed solution how this should be done

Comment: Just create custom theme using this link. https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html

Comment: Let me know after you can done this.

Comment: actually I have to this task without using the design portion

Comment: from the code itself I have to call the required class and perform the task

Comment: Check I update the code.

Comment: @Naiwrita09 Take a look at my answer below. It walks you through how to achieve this requirement using a custom-module under app/code instead of via via a Theme customization.